# Using jQuery Ajax and NodeJS : Getting returned values

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to send the `returned` value from Node to client, but I got stuck. Why I can't see the username?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/login', function(req,res) {
  var returned = req.body.username;
  console.log(returned); // returns undefined, but it works if I remove jquery post (normal post works), so I think there's a problem with req.body.username since it returns undefined.
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".submit").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post(
           "/login", function(returned) {
               $('.result').html(returned);
           }
       )
   });
});
```

login.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
    body
        form(method='post', action='login')
            input(type='text', name="username")
            input(type='submit', class="submit")
        div(class="result")
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js")
    script(src="javascripts/index.js")
```

Comment: returns undefined, I probably have an issue with bodyParser. I'll edit the question details in a few minutes.

Comment: in your $.post, you didn't pass along any data with the request, so undefined should be expected.

Comment: That's correct. Now I'm sad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your $.post, you didn't pass the username, therefore `undefined` is what you should expect serverside. Passing the data only takes a minor change:

```
   $.post(
       "/login", $('form').serialize() function(returned) {
           $('.result').html(returned);
       }
   )
```

I would suggest though to use the form's submit event instead, makes the code a little bit easier (subjective).

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
    body
        form(id='myform', method='post', action='login')
            input(type='text', name="username")
            input(type='submit', class="submit")
        div(class="result")
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js")
    script(src="javascripts/index.js")
```

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post(
           "/login", $(this).serialize(), function(returned) {
               $('.result').html(returned);
           }
       )
   });
});
```

It also avoids the possibility of the form getting incorrectly submitted without the click event triggering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.